# Sum of values from two different entities in JPA

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have two sums to calculate in JPA, from two different entities:

```
SELECT SUM(da.debtorBalance) FROM DebtorAccount da WHERE <conditions for DebtorAccounts>
```

and

```
SELECT SUM(mda.debtorBalance) FROM MasterDebtorAccount mda WHERE <conditions for MasterDebtorAccounts>
```

What I need is sum of this sums. Is it possible by JPAQL? Or I need to run two separate queries and add this in the application?

Comment: Keep It Simple (S): Two queries are not going to be significantly slower and will be easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't in strict JPQL.

In SQL, it would be something like

SELECT SUM(a) FROM (SELECT da.debtorBalance a from DebtorAccount UNION SELECT mda.debtorBalance a FROM MasterDebtorAccount)

JPA does not support UNION, although several implementations do.

And no, you can't do this without union because relational algebra means that you begin with DebtorAccount * MasterDebtorBalance and after that you refine it through conditions / aplying functions.

Comment: @aramis Look what I have found! http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/jpql-vs-sql-have-both-with-eclipselink.html. Look at the SQL keyword, that allows any SQL in JPQL. Anyway, I still stand by my comment of KISS.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried?

```
SELECT SUM(SUM(da.debtorBalance), SUM(mda.debtorBalance)) 
FROM DebtorAccount da, MasterDebtorAccount mda
WHERE (<conditions for DebtorAccounts>) OR (<conditions for MasterDebtorAccounts>)
```

Regadrs,

Comment: I have 14 DebtorAccounts, and 2 MasterDebtorAccounts, and this query, modified only SUM(SUM(...), SUM(...)) to da.debtorBalance, mda.debtorBalance, gives me more than thousand results.

Comment: In plain SQL, that would mean that you get the cartesian product (da * mda) and from that you get the sum of that. That is, the result would be SUM(da.debtorBalance) * count(mda) + SUM(mda.debtorBalance) * count(da)

Comment: if you perform queries without the end sum will also go bad data? "SELECT SUM(da.debtorBalance), SUM(mda.debtorBalance) FROM..."

Comment: @amorfis, if you had done it right you should have up to 28 records (unless you add additional tables in the join)